# How to fix CS0029 error caused by generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am attempting to write a static `Parse` method in class `Matrix<T, V>`, which is responsible for constructing a `Matrix<T, Vector<T>>` of the correct dimensions from a string (in this class, matrices are backed by row vectors). Several subclasses of `Matrix<T, V>` exist (e.g. `Matrix2x<T>`, `Matrix2x2<T>`, etc.). The different subclasses have different dimensions in addition to different get/set accessibility. This code is being adapted from existing, functional Java code. A friend and I are experimenting with using C# instead of Java, which we are more familiar with.

The problem is that these parameterized subclasses cannot be converted (either implicitly or with a cast) to the base class parameterized with the `Vector<T>` base class. It is unclear to me why the following code does not compile, though I imagine it is caused by the concreteness of C#'s generics as compared to Java's generics.

I wondered if possibly the compilation error could have been caused by attempting to return a Matrix parameterized by type `Vector<T>`, because it is abstract. Changing `Vector<T>` to a concrete class (complete with dummy methods) did not solve the issue; the compilation error persisted.

```
public static Matrix<T, Vector<T>> Parse(Func<string, Scalar<T>> parser, string str, bool mutable = false) {
    MutableVector2D<T> mv2 = new MutableVector2D<T>();
    Vector2D<T> v2 = mv2;
    Vector<T> v = v2;

    MutableMatrix2x2<T> mm22 = new MutableMatrix2x2<T>();
    Matrix2x2<T, MutableVector2D<T>> m22 = mm22;
    Matrix2x2<T, Vector2D<T>> m22_ = m22; // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
    Matrix2x<T, Vector2D<T>> m2 = m22_;
    Matrix<T, Vector2D<T>> m = m2;
    Matrix<T, Vector<T>> answer = m; // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
    return answer;
}
```

As shown in the code snippet, a `MutableVector2D<T>` may be implicitly converted to a `Vector2D<T>` and to a `Vector<T>`. However, a `MutableMatrix2x2<T>` may be implicitly converted to a `Matrix2x2<T, MutableVector2D<T>>`, but not to a `Matrix2x2<T, Vector2D<T>>`, which puzzles me. A cast to `Matrix2x2<T, Vector2D<T>>` (which shouldn't be necessary as I understand the problem) solved nothing.

The relevant class headers are listed below:

```
public sealed class MutableVector2D<T> : Vector2D<T> {...}
public abstract class Vector2D<T> : Vector<T> {...}
public abstract class Vector<T> : ICopyable<Vector<T>>, IParser<Vector<T>>, IComparable<Vector<T>>, IEnumerable<Scalar<T>> {...}

public sealed class MutableMatrix2x2<T> : Matrix2x2<T, MutableVector2D<T>> {...}
public abstract class Matrix2x2<T, V> : Matrix2x<T, V> where V : Vector2D<T> {...}
public abstract class Matrix2x<T, V> : Matrix<T, V> where V : Vector2D<T> {...}
public abstract class Matrix<T, V> : ICopyable<Matrix<T, V>>, IParser<Matrix<T, Vector<T>>>, IComparable<Matrix<T, Vector<T>>>, IEnumerable<Scalar<T>> where V : Vector<T> {...}
```

To be clear, the `Parse` method above has nothing to do with the actual parsing operation. It is simply an attempt to debug the compilation error. In case anyone wants to know, the following is the actual, non-compiling `Parse` method:

```
public static Matrix<T, Vector<T>> Parse(Func<string, Scalar<T>> parser, string str, bool mutable = false) {
    string[] lines = str.Split('\n');
    int m = lines.Length;
    if (m == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot construct a Matrix with 0 rows.", "str");
    }
    string line = lines[0];
    int leftIndex = line.IndexOf('[') + 1;
    string[] entries = line.Substring(leftIndex, line.IndexOf(']', leftIndex)).Split(',');
    int n = entries.Length;
    if (n < 2) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot construct a Matrix with fewer than 2 columns.");
    }
    Scalar<T>[,] parsedEntries = new Scalar<T>[m, n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        parsedEntries[0, j] = parser.Invoke(entries[j]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        line = lines[i];
        leftIndex = line.IndexOf('[') + 1;
        entries = line.Substring(leftIndex, line.IndexOf(']', leftIndex)).Split(',');
        if (entries.Length != n) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot construct a Matrix from a jagged array of entries", "str");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            parsedEntries[i, j] = parser.Invoke(entries[j]);
        }
    }
    switch (n) {
        case 2:
            if (m == n) {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrix2x2<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrix2x2<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            } else {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrix2x<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrix2x<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            }
        case 3:
            if (m == n) {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrix3x3<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrix3x3<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            } else {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrix3x<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrix3x<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            }
        case 4:
            if (m == n) {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrix4x4<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrix4x4<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            } else {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrix4x<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrix4x<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            }
        default:
            if (m == n) {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrixNxN<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrixNxN<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            } else {
                if (mutable) {
                    return new MutableMatrixNx<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                } else {
                    return new ImmutableMatrixNx<T>(parsedEntries); // Does not compile (compilation error CS0029)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Just because two types have a particular inheritance relationship, that doesn't mean that a generic parameterised over those types exhibits the *same* relationship. a `MutableVector2D` inherits from `Vector2D` but e.g. a `List<MutableVector2D>` *doesn't* inherit from `List<Vector2D>`. You have a similar issue in your code. There's no general fix because it's *type unsafe* in general to allow the assignment, especially in the face of mutability.

Comment: See [Eric Lippert's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/) on variance with generics. Look into using interfaces.